# Zeppelin Spark cant connect Mesos DC/OS

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, apache-zeppelin

I installed DC/OS and install spark with **dcos package install --package-version=1.0.1-1.6.1-2 spark**

Spark was installed successfully and i'm able to open spark driver program page on the master node.

Now, i trying to setup zeppelin and connect it to the mesos cluster. I used next env variables in zeppelin-env.sh:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark-1.6.1
export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libmesos.so 
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI=http://downloads.mesosphere.io.s3.amazonaws.com/spark/assets/spark-1.6.1.tgz
export ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.executor.uri=$SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI"
```

And set up spark master url via zeppelin UI to **mesos://myhostname:5050**

Could you help me understand what is wrong, I have following error message in my logs:

```
I0810 14:10:36.157269   201 sched.cpp:222] Version: 0.28.1
I0810 14:10:36.160846   192 sched.cpp:326] New master detected at master@192.168.1.22:5050
I0810 14:10:36.161087   192 sched.cpp:336] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
I0810 14:10:36.162654   192 sched.cpp:703] Framework registered with 4fdf49cd-d2cf-4c31-8204-d71f4ea03c15-0064
Exception in thread "Thread-38" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Map.getOrDefault(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.mesos.MesosSchedulerUtils$class.passKerberosConf(MesosSchedulerUtils.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.mesos.CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend.passKerberosConf(CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.mesos.CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend.createCommand(CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.mesos.CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend$$anonfun$buildMesosTasks$1.apply(CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend.scala:418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.mesos.CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend$$anonfun$buildMesosTasks$1.apply(CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend.scala:394)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.mesos.CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend.buildMesosTasks(CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend.scala:394)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.mesos.CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend.handleMatchedOffers(CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend.scala:338)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.mesos.CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend.resourceOffers(CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend.scala:310)
I0810 14:10:36.193603   192 sched.cpp:1937] Asked to abort the driver
I0810 14:10:36.193646   192 sched.cpp:1173] Aborting framework '4fdf49cd-d2cf-4c31-8204-d71f4ea03c15-0064'
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I used spark from http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz and it works fine now.